# interrupted vs isinterrupted implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I wonder if anyone can please clear my confusion about the implementation issue that I am having; if Thread.interrupted() clears a flag of the current thread and also tells you if current thread was interrupted, my lack of understanding is the static scope.  How does a static function knows my current thread instance ?

Thanks, just trying to understand the internals.

Answer (score 0):

The current thread is looked up using [`Thread.currentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29) inside the method `Thread.interrupted()`. `Thread.currentThread()` returns a reference to the calling thread.

Comment: But I still don't understand the mechanism here on how does a static function gets a reference to my actual current thread instance. I would love to really understand the pattern, code, etc.

Comment: @Basixp `currentThread()` is a `native` method. It's up to the JVM to figure it out. You can look up the native source code if you have time.

Comment: looks like I need to do more research here but appreciate your responses. native method seems too general and are all native methods static?

Comment: `native` methods do not have to be static. `native` simply means that the method is implemented with native code (usually C/C++) and accessed by the JVM via JNI.